# I want to show the antd datepicker in a drawer from datepicker field that is outside the drawer and will show inline is there a way

Tags: reactjs, mobile, datepicker, antd, desktop

I am following Sastaticket you can also check from there in different screen sizes I need to show the datepicker according to screen size if on a desktop window the datepicker will show normally that is already showing but when on a mobile screen i need to open a drawer and then the datepicker should show inside the drawer with inline style i have created the datepicker field outside the drawer .is there a way to do this i am using antd datepicker

I have tried to create the custom drawer and when on mobile screen only the drawer is showing and not the datepicker because i do not know how to call the respective datepicker in a onclick function like in the jquery we have .datepicker() for custom styling and other stuff

```
<DatePicker placeholder='EndDate'onClick={ShowWithPopOver} onChange={onChange} name='EndDatePicker' id='EndDatePicker' style={{ border: "transparent", boxShadow: "none" }} />
```

and here is my function code

```
  function ShowWithPopOver()
  {
    if(window.innerWidth>700)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        debugger
        const el = document.getElementById('MobileDatePickerOverlay');
        el.classList.add('mlk-drawer-open');
       
    }
  
  }
```

if mobile view then add class to this view MobileDatePickerOverly to show the view and after that the datepicker will show in that view as inline

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post images explaining the expected output for desktop and mobile ? It will be helpful to solve your query.

Comment: I am following sastaticket you can get the idea from there in different screens.I am new here so donot know how to add images

Comment: I am not allowed to share the images i think i am new to the stackoverflow that is why